# Removing/Showing Elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a site where 3 images, which are to be clicked on, toggle 3 different divs/elements. What I want is each click-able image to show a certain element, whilst removing the elements previously shown.

So image1 will show div1, image2 will show div2, image3 will show div3. The elements before have to be literally removed, not just hidden from sight.

If possible, is there a way to save the option for when someone lasts visits the site with cookies?

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code in Fiddle or hire a front-end developer

Comment: I've created the 3 elements, and assigned them with div ids. That's all I've done so far - I'm not too familiar with Jscript.

Comment: So instead of asking for code that you're not familiar with and most probably won't understand, you might want to go and learn the basics.

Comment: Create a fiddle for the code in : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @AlexInorbit, can you please post the code you have so far?  Are you familiar with CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick solution using jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/45HKG/

```
$('.image').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.box').addClass('hidden');
    var imageNumber = $(this).attr('id').replace('image','');
    $('#div'+ imageNumber).removeClass('hidden');
});
```